# Duda función callback. Función anónima o función definida?

Tags: javascript

estoy comenzando con Javascript y me surge una duda a al hora de llamar a una función dentro de otra.

si tengo este código:

```
const boton = document.getElementById('boton');
boton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('hola');
});
```

Aquí todo funciona con normalidad, botón a la escucha del evento y muestra mensaje en consola al ser pulsado.

Pero si creo el evento de esta siguiente manera me muestra el mensaje en consola antes de pulsar el botón, como es esto posible?

```
boton.addEventListener('click', llamadaFuncion());

function llamadaFuncion() {
  console.log('hola');
}
```

Comment: Porque lo estás haciendo tú, estás llamando a la función explicitamente **al poner los paréntesis**. Quítalos: `boton.addEventListener( 'click', llamadaFuncion );`. Al ponerlos, estás diciendo *me interesa el resultado de llamar a esta función*.

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente así se ejecuta cuando toca.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin ser un experto en JS, esta es la estrucura típica de un *listener* de evento en *vainilla* JS:

```
const boton = document.getElementById('boton');
boton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('hola');
});
```

o

```
const boton = document.getElementById('boton');
boton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    console.log('hola', event.target);
});
```

donde `addEventListener`, segun la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), recibe como primer parámetro un string que indica el tipo de evento a escuchar, y como segundo parámetro el *objecto* que recibe la notificación del evento o una función.

Dentro de esta función puedes implementar tu código o llamar a otras funciones.

Por ejemplo:

```
const boton = document.getElementById('boton');
boton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('hola');
    llamadaFuncion();
});

function llamadaFuncion() {
  console.log('hola');
}
```

Puedes indicar la función a llamar directamente como segundo parámetro de `addEventListener`:

```
const boton = document.getElementById('boton');
boton.addEventListener('click', llamadaFuncion);

function llamadaFuncion() {
  console.log('hola');
}
```

En este caso, pierdes de la oportunidad de ejecutar otro código dentro del callback, más allá del incluido en la función que estas llamando, lo que a veces es deseable. En este caso debes poner esta función sin paréntesis, ya que estas pasando la referencia a esta función, para que se ejecute en el momento en que se produzca el evento.

Cuando añades con paréntesis una función, esa función se ejecuta en el momento, es decir si la llamada esta dentro de una función, cuando se llama a esa función, si esta fuera cuando se carga el script.